# autofs NFS mount directory hung

Tags: nfs, automount, autofs

I have a problem when executing "df -h" command it hungs, I know since there is a unreachable/not responding NFS path this is causing the hung. All my scripts dependent of df -h is also piling up because of this.

The only way is to manually lazy unmount (umount -l ) such automount filesystems.

But is there a way to define some options in autofs so that if there is a non-responding NFS path it should automatically unmount such directories in autofs?

Or

Any scripts to fix such issues?

Comment: if you have a NFS stale try this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/617610/stale-nfs-file-handle-after-reboot

Answer (score 0):

If you have a NFS stale, try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/617610/stale-nfs-file-handle-after-reboot

There is a script in the post that you can use.